# watchPosition() and getCurrentPosition

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

What is the difference between `getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()`. I read several articles about `getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()`. But none of was clear to me. As far as I'm understand `getCurrentPosition()` update location only one time But `watchPosition()` continuously update location. I'm I right??

Comment: You're right, `watchPosition()` executes the callback everytime a new position is available, `getCurrentPosition()` executes the callback only once when the first position is available.

Comment: Did anyone below answer your question or do you still have a question?

Answer (score 5):

`getCurrentPosition()` gives currentPosition latitude and longtitude values,which fires only once. Where as `watchPosition()` gives currentPosition latitude and longtitude values continuously. If position changed(assume you are in a moving vehicle,then `watchPosition()` will give result.Then you will come to know the result of this  )

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The `getCurrentPosition()` callback is fired once and `watchPosition()` callback is fired continuously. [Good reading on this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation).

Answer (score 0):

`watchPosition` fired each time your device position changes (with interval specified in fn params). `getCurrentPostion` only once.

`watchPosition` actually analogue of `setInterval` fn and also returns id that can be used to stop iterative process by using `clearWatch`.